# table lock is transactions and multiple query access the same table

Tags: sql-server, transactions, locking

I'm using the transaction in .net. I use to insert data into four tables with different methods. 
since it is order inflow method, busy in peak hours. The table used for order submission, the same table used for bulk order processing and batch job processing at the same time. so sometime we are getting timeout in any of the above 3 areas.

Mean to say single table used in major 3 transaction areas same time.

1. order submission.(insert operation)
2. Job(updating a column)
3. Bulk order processing(updating a column)

Is that due to locking in order submission affect other transaction also.

Nolock is not used in transactions.

Comment: what is your question here ?

Comment: same table used in 3 different scenario transactions for insert and update. when all the scenario transaction executes at same time. I'm getting time out in any one of the scenarios. Is this due to transaction locking? if so suggest me some solution. thanks @TheGameiswar

Comment: I am hoping you are updating based on proper index ... then no another way than increasing time out . and put serializable  hint if update have any issue..